# firebase user number is showing null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i want to display the user phone number to the screen but it is showing null on the screen

```
String _userId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      _userId = user.phoneNumber;
    });
    print(_userId);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child:  Text("$_userId")
                    ?? CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your Firebase query to outside your build method. The build method is constantly being run as your Widget is rebuilt. Ideally you would implement it this way:

```
// _userId needs to be initiated with a blank value
String _userId = '';

@override
void initState() {
  loadCurrentUser();
  super.initState();
}

void loadCurrentUser(){
  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
    setState(() {
      _userId = user.phoneNumber;
    });
  });
}
```

This way, as soon as the information is loaded your view will be updated.

Comment: what do you mean by loadcurrentuser() i didnt get it and its not working saying this method is not define for my class

Comment: It's the method I wrote right below the `initState`, did you copy the whole code?

Comment: If this fixed your issue, please mark it as the correct answer. It will help future users find their answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), the FutureBuilder widget comes with Flutter and makes it easy to work with async data sources. Therefore you need to do the following:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child : FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                               print(snapshot);
                    return Text(snapshot.data.uid);
                    }
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                )
```

The `future` property will contain the asynchronous computation to which this builder is currently connected, possibly null. Also you should be using a `Stateful Widget`.

Comment: Cool answer, as I never heard of `FutureBuilder` before (only `StreamBuilder`).

Answer (score 1):

You should show more of your code but it appears you're using a StatelessWidget which means that after that Future returns, the value of `_userId` in the build method is not going to update by itself. The simplest way would be to use a StatefulWidget and call `setState` within your Future to update the value.

Also your line `Text("$_userId")?? CircularProgressIndicator()` won't work correctly because of the same issue, but you need to show one widget or the other depending on the value of `_userId`.